# Only hours and minutes in input type="time"

Tags: javascript, input, time

Is it possible to allow only to enter hours and minutes into the `<input type="time />` without seconds?

Comment: The marked dup is not identical (there, the OP wants hours only, not minutes also) but the goal and sentiment are basically the same.

Comment: Well, I am not sure why my question got duplicate. It's not the same question and from that one I didn't get the answer. This is going to be reported

Comment: Did you read my comment? In the dup, the OP is asking the same as you - but for hours only, not minutes. The mechanics of any such solution, and the sentiment of the question, are, therefore, the same. You will find that any moderation agrees with this.

Comment: I read your comment, went to the link marked as an answer to my question, and found a partially answered question. Tried to use their technique, didn't get it to work. I would like to read someone else's explanation along with the answer to my question, so if this is a duplicate question can you please tell me where should I ask questions to get a better-explained approach. What does stack overflow suggest?

Comment: If you have a question about the running of SO itself please ask in meta. I read the dup, and it did seem like there is no cross-browser, certain way of achieving what you want with the `time` input - you may need a more bespoke solution (perhaps involving two inputs rather than one.)